# R function to combine lists but prioritize the values in one of them

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function to combine multiple lists, usually between 2 and 4, that will weed out duplicates and hopefully (if possible) prioritize the values of one of the lists. Is this possible? It's better explained with code:

```
PassOpts <- function(in1 = list(), in2 = list(), in3 = list(), in4 = list(){
    c(in1, in2, in3, in4)
}
opts1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4)
opts2 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4)
opts3 <- list(a = 5, b = 10)
combinedOpts <- PassOpts(opts1, opts2, opts3)
```

Ideally what I want is for it to be possible to 'prioritize' the list that is the most different from the rest, so in this case I would want for `combinedOpts` to be a list of `a = 5, b = 10, c = 4`. I'm using it as a way to set and combine default and also user input options. 
Thanks

**Solved, ended up doing this as I realized the latest input (i.e. with 3 inputs in3) would be the one I want to use as default, so did as follows

```
PassOpts <- function(in1 = list(), in2 = list(), in3 = list(), in4 = list()){
if(length(in4) != 0){
    in4Names <- names(in4)
    rList <- in4
    temp <- c(in1,in2,in3)
    tempNames <- names(temp)
    for(i in 1:length(tempNames)){
        nam <- tempNames[i]
        if(!(nam %in% in4Names)){
            in4Names <- c(in4Names,nam)
            rList[nam] <- temp[nam]
        }
    }
}else if(length(in3) != 0){
    in3Names <- names(in3)
    rList <- in3
    temp <- c(in1,in2)
    tempNames <- names(temp)
    for(i in 1:length(tempNames)){
        nam <- tempNames[i]
        if(!(nam %in% in3Names)){
            in3Names <- c(in3Names, nam)
            rList[nam] <- temp[nam]
        }
    }
}else if(length(in2) != 0){
    in2Names <- names(in2)
    rList <- in2
    temp <- in1
    tempNames <- names(temp)
    for(i in 1:length(tempNames)){
        nam <- tempNames[i]
        if(!(nam %in% in2Names)){
            in2Names <- c(in2Names, nam)
            rList[nam] <- temp[nam]
        }
    }
}else{
    return(in1)
}
return(rList)
}
```

Comment: If its only a small set of lists then instead of vectorizing it might be better to just do it iteratively. You also need to define what you mean by "most different". The example you have given could also be obtained by picking the max.

Answer (score 1):

Looks likes you are looking of most unique number.

Here is how I would do:
    1. aggregate input lists
    2. find out the most unique one for each key

```
PassOpts <- function(listOfList){
  resList = list()

  # reduce lists by key
  for (l in listOfList){
    for (i in 1:length(l)){
      key = names(l[i])
      value = l[[i]]
      resList[[key]] = c(resList[[key]], value)
    }
  }

  # found most diffent one for each key
  findDiff <- function(elements){
    countTable = table(elements)
    minCount = min(countTable)
    return(names(countTable)[countTable == minCount])
  }
  return(lapply(resList, FUN=findDiff))
}

opts1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4)
opts2 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4)
opts3 <- list(a = 5, b = 10)

combinedOpts <- PassOpts(list(opts1, opts2, opts3))
```